# How do I display the row number count in a dynamic javascript table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, datatable

I'm looping over an array on the front end using ejs and displaying the data in a bootstrap 5 table. The table is dynamic so rows will be added and deleted with time.

All the data is coming through without an error and the table is populating, however, I'd like to have the first column show the "count" for each row. Eg., "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc".

I've tried using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) without any success and since the code already exists in a loop, creating another loop requires me to switch my ejs syntax and I lose the ability to count the length of the array.

Below is my client side code that yields value `-1` down the entire `#` column for each row:

```
 <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <a href="" class="a1" onclick="exportTableToCSV(null, 'text.csv')">Export to csv</a>
 </div>
 <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Gender</th>
      <th scope="col">Age</th>
      <th scope="col">Clicked IG</th>
      <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
      <th scope="col">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% for (let fan of artist.fans){%>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= artist.fans.indexOf(fan.id) %></th>
      <td><%= fan.email %></td>
      <td><%= fan.gender %></td>
      <td><%= fan.age %></td>
      <td><%= fan.subscribed %></td>
      <td><%= fan.dateAdded %></td>
      <td style="padding-left: 2rem;">
        <button onclick="removeRow()" ></button>
         </td>
      <td style="padding-left: 2rem;"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></td>
      <% } %> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

If I switch `artist.fans.indexOf(fan.id)` with *just* `fan.id` I get the corresponding objectId for each fan email object.

If I switch `artist.fans.indexOf(fan.id)` with `artist.fans.length` I get `7` down the `#` column for each row.

Here's my db model:

```
const artistSchema = new Schema({
image: [ImageSchema], 
genre: [ String ], 
fans: [{ 
    email: String, 
    subscribed: String, 
    gender: String, 
    age: Number 
        dateAdded: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
                }
      }], 
 });
```

How do I get each row to be numbered?

Comment: Also, `indexOf` has a runtime complexity of `O(n)` so it's inadvisable to use that function inside a loop over the same array... and it's only defined on `Array.prototype` so it isn't available on other kinds of iterables, such as `NodeList`.

Comment: The row-number value is not a "count" value, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you used `fan.id` as a search param in `artist.fans.indexOf(fan.id)` which is not directly accessible throw the `artist.fans` so instead you need to use another method that accepts `comparing function` so you can compare their id

try to use

```
<th scope="row"><%= artist.fans.findIndex(f=> f.id == fan.id) %></th>
```

Comment: `findIndex` is still `O(n)` so this ejs template will have a runtime complexity of `O(n^2)` which won't scale beyond a few dozen elements.

Comment: This works, thanks @Mohammed esam ! I added a "+1" to the end of the code because the row numbers were starting at index 0. Here's how it looks now: `<th scope="row"><%= artist.fans.findIndex(f=> f.id == fan.id) +1 %></th>`. Is there any truth to Dai's comment?

Comment: as @Dai said  if your application will scale and contain like 1000s of data that would be expensive so it's better to store the index in the object itself, and if you working on small scale app then it's fine

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

Just do this:

```js
<% for( const fan of artist.fans.map( ( e, index ) => ({ index, ...e }) ) ) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= fan.index %></th>
    <td><%= fan.email %></td>
    <!-- etc -->
</tr>

<% }%>
```

### Explanation:

> I'd like to have the first column show the "count" for each row. Eg., "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc".

- That's not a "count". I would refer to that as "the row-number" (if 1-based) or "row-index" (if 0-based).
- If you're using SQL to get your data then you can just use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your query and map it to some new `number` property in your `Fan` type.

  - Note that a `ROW_NUMBER()` value is kinda meaningless without a well-defined `ORDER BY` criteria.
- [**Don't use `indexOf` in a loop**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463517/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-indexof-inside-loops): `indexOf` has a runtime complexity of `O(n)` so it's inadvisable to use that function inside a loop over the same array as that will give you `O(n^2)` runtime, which is *very bad*.

  - This also applies to other `O(n)` *reduction* functions like `findIndex`, `find`, `includes`, and `lastIndexOf`.
  - Also, `indexOf` (and others)  only defined on `Array.prototype`, so it isn't available on other kinds of iterables, such as `NodeList`.
- Within ejs, [you can use an overload of `Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which gives you the `index` of each `element`, and stick the `index` into each `element` object, like so:

```js
const fansWithIndex = artist.fans
    .map( function( element, index ) {
        element.index = index;
        return element;
    } );

<% for( const fan of fansWithIndex ) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= fan.index %></th>
    <td><%= fan.email %></td>
    <!-- etc -->
</tr>

<% }%>
```

...though FP purists (like myself) would argue that the above example is bad code because it mutates source data, and instead `Object.assign` should be used instead. Also, the long-form `function` can be made simpler with an arrow-function `=>`, like this:

```js
const fansWithIndex = artist.fans.map( ( e, idx ) => Object.assign( { index: idx }, e ) );

<% for( const fan of fansWithIndex ) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= fan.index %></th>
    <td><%= fan.email %></td>
    <!-- etc -->
</tr>

<% }%>
```

This can be simplified further:

- As an alternative to `Object.assign` [the object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...obj` can be used:

  - `{ index: idx, ...e }` is *almost* semantically identical to `Object.assign( { index: idx }, e )`.

    - The difference is that `Object.assign` will invoke custom `setter` functions, whereas the `...` syntax does not.
  - Caution: when immediately returning an object-literal from within `map` you [will need to wrap the object-literal's braces `{}` in parentheses `()` to prevent the braces being parsed as function body delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333992/what-do-parenthesis-surrounding-brackets-in-the-return-statement-of-an-es6-arrow), hence the `=> ({ foo: bar })` instead of `=> { foo: bar }`.
- The `index: idx` can be simplified by renaming the `idx` parameter to `index` and putting just `{ index, ...e }`.
- Like so:

```js
const fansWithIndex = artist.fans.map( ( e, index ) => ({ index, ...e }) );

<% for( const fan of fansWithIndex ) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= fan.index %></th>
    <td><%= fan.email %></td>
    <!-- etc -->
</tr>

<% }%>
```

- Because the `artist.fans.map(...)` part is a single expression with a single output you can now inline it directly into your `for(of)` statement, like so:

```js
<% for( const fan of artist.fans.map( ( e, index ) => ({ index, ...e }) ) ) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= fan.index %></th>
    <td><%= fan.email %></td>
    <!-- etc -->
</tr>

<% }%>
```

Comment: Hi @dai - thanks for the comprehensive answer and explaining most of it (super valuable for me as I'm still beginner/intermediate level). When I drop in your code the row-numbers* come through but the rest of the data in the table falls out.. Any ideas why email/gender/etc are now missing?

Comment: @econobro Please provide some sample data and your current code in a Pastebin/JSFiddle example and I'll try to reproduce the issue you're having.